# Is this assessment of the damage caused to Azerbaijan during the Nagorno-Karabakh war accurate?

Tags: war, armenia, azerbaijan, caucasus

Armenia and Azerbaijan fought a mutually bloody war between 1988 and 1994. The Azerbaijan government (specifically, its embassy in Latvia, of all places) said that the Armenians caused all the following damage. It seems likely to be exaggerated, but by how much?

http://www.embassyaz.lv/en/azerbaijan/armenian-occupation

> Destructions caused by the aggression of Armenia against Azerbaijan 
>   Settlements - 890 Houses - 150.000 Public Buildings - 7.000 Schools -
>   693 Kindergartens - 855 Health Care Facilities - 695 Libraries - 927
>   Temples - 44 Mosques - 9 Historical Palaces - 9 Historical Monuments
>   and Museums - 464 Museum Exhibits - 40.000 Industrial and Agricultural
>   Enterprises - 6.000 Motor Ways - 800 km Bridges - 160 Water Pipelines
>   - 2.300 km Gas Pipelines - 2.000 km Electricity Lines - 15.000 km Forests - 280.000 ha Sowing Area - 1.000.000 ha Irrigation Systems -
>   1.200 km

Comment: The text on the linked page is clearly biased (e.g. passage about events in Sumgayit). The numbers are probably deduced from the total war damage caused by both sides. It seems just impossible that anyone knows what was done exactly by one side of conflict.

Comment: But there are analysts who work to try to wade through the bias and estimate the actual damage. I think a superior question would be, "Does anyone have a responsible estimate of the damage?" Has any scholarly or historical study been done to assess the damage of the war in question?